# How to get upload progress from CloseableHttpClient POST?

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

I'm working on a Maven plugin that will ultimately POST a binary file to a server.  I'm using HTTPComponents 4.3.  I'm pretty new to Java and the Apache libraries, but beyond that how do I extract upload progress from `CloseableHttpClient.execute()`?

I intend to log the progress on the command line, either by bytes sent or percentage.

```
CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpPost post = createHttpPost(); //just sets up the HttpPost object
HttpEntity entity = createHttpEntity(); //adds the multipart
post.setEntity(entity);

HttpResponse response;
try {
    getLog().info("Executing request.");
    response = client.execute(post);
} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    //handle
} catch (IOException e) {
    //handle
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Bytes written in the Output buffer implementation used by the Post will give you the data for your progressMeter....

Using debug and or review of the 4.3 api docs, you will need to determine the actual implementation of the buffer i/o for your Posts.... There are lots of interfaces and it may take you some time to find , but here are some wild guesses about what may be doing io for a POST & CloseableHttpClient...

[SessionOutputBufferImpl](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/io/SessionOutputBufferImpl.html) is one - note the I/O from which you can capture metrics for a progressBar on the Post action.

Another that you should look at is [BHttpConnectionBase](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-core-ga/httpcore/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/BHttpConnectionBase.html)